# Is there any notable difference to take into account when roasting Cicer arietinum vs. Pisum sativum?

Tags: roasting, recipe-changing

I recently got a freebie bag of snacks that according to the ingredient list included
Pisum sativum ('doperwt' in Dutch). But since buying these snacks in the store seems pretty overpriced compared to the price of a can of Pisum sativum, some spices and some electricity for roasting, I was thinking of making my own.

While looking for recipes, I came across loads of recipes for roasted Cicer arietinum ('kikkererwt' in Dutch). Even when searching specifically for 'geroosterde doperwten recept' (instead of just 'geroosterde erwt') and 'Pisum sativum roosteren', I only get recipes that use Cicer arietinum or that are about roasting an entirely different vegetable, served in combination with regularly cooked Pisum sativum. Which makes me wonder if the regular Pisum sativum may be unsuited to being roasted in an oven at home.

Are there any notable differences between the two when used in cooking, specifically roasting? Would I be better off just following a recipe using Cicer arietinum, or can I just replace the Cicer arietinum with Pisum sativum while making no changes to the rest of the recipe?

Comment: You will get much better results if you put the English words for these. Pisum Sativum is a Green Pea and Cicer Arietinum is a Chickpea.

Comment: There's a recipe for roasted green peas in English [here](https://www.cookitrealgood.com/roasted-peas/)

Comment: Instead of buying canned peas, buy the dry ones (whole, not split) and soak them for 8-24h before roasting. You'll get better results.